# save a same value using unique constraint with different foreign key id in grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I have a domaing named Thana where I save thanaName with the parent id of district. I have used unique constraint for thanaName. When I save thana with a name suppose 'Thana A' with the district foreign key value 1 it's saved. When I want to save the 'Thana A' again with district foreign key value 2 it would not save it because of unique constraint. But I need to do it cause here district are different although the thanaName are same. Can anyone please help me on this please ? Thanks a lot.

```
    class Thana {

    String thanaName
    District district

    static constraints = {
        thanaName unique: true // each instance must have a unique name.
    }

    static mapping = {
        table('thana')
        version(false)
        district column: 'district_id'
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not perfectly clear what you are asking here, but if you post your domain classes it may make things clearer.

Comment: How is this question different from the previous one?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore I have edited and posted my thana domain. Is it ok ?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Thanks a lot. It is answered in previous question of yours. I didn't noticed. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi-column unique constraints, here is the link of the documentation:

[Unique](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/unique.html)